# Pass an array to .net webservice in ios sdk

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I like to call the json web service through my iphone app.

I try to pass the array like as follow:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"key",nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:venueId,nil];
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
NSString* jsonString = [jsonDictionary JSONRepresentation];


NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);
```

**Call to webservice**

```
SBJSON *json = [SBJSON new];
    json.humanReadable = YES;
    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
 NSString *service = @"/DerializeDataTable";
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"n\":\"%@\"}",jsonString];

    NSLog(@"request string:%@",requestString);
```

**Requsted String**

```
{"n":"{"key":["4e78b7f7483bc8fe83ed2bf9","4de248a21520b8ceaabd9197","4f0d502be4b0dd89303e6bde","4f2a79a1e4b0b052a3f37633","500ebf52e4b0edbb8dbc7e9c","4d63a047a45b5481c872032d"]}"}
```

But can't able to get the response. 
**I don't know what is the reason.**

**I don't know the any problem on my side or server side.**

Answer (score 0):

You haven't posted the code where you actually send the request off to your web service, so it is going to be hard to help you.

The first thing you should do is isolate whether the problem is with your client (the app) or your server. You can do this by logging the response you get when you send the message - it sounds as if you're getting no response, in which case you might be better off examining your server logs to see if the request ever reaches your server. You might find it useful to use a proxy to actually see the network traffic as it leaves your app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I got the response as like: ExceptionType = "System.ArgumentException";
    Message = "Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (9): {\"n\":\"{\"key\":[\"4e78b7f7483bc8fe83ed2bf9\",\"4de248a21520b8ceaabd9197\",\"4f0d502be4b0dd89303e6bde\",\"4fc4538de4b005f3f3dcb75f\",\"4d63a047a45b5481c872032d\"]}\"}";
    StackTrace = " at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)
\nat System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)

Comment: JSON string that you are passing in the request body has error. Validate the JSON using http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: `n` is my parameter name and the `key` is the key for that parameter. If i try to validate the the json string then it pass the validation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have extra quotes in there.  I think you mean:
    {"n":{"key":   ["4e78b7f7483bc8fe83ed2bf9","4de248a21520b8ceaabd9197","4f0d502be4b0dd89303e6bde","4f2a79a1e4b0b052a3f37633","500ebf52e4b0edbb8dbc7e9c","4d63a047a45b5481c872032d"]}}